# Obtaining column names and characteristics from a df. R

Tags: r, dataframe

I can´t find how to print a table in the console with all the names of the variables in a data frame along with the charcatristics of each variable (column): is it integer or a character? and how many NAs each variable has.

I looking for something similar to how Rstudio shows the dataframes:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `str(data_1)`.

Comment: Thanks... feel stupid now. One question. How do I get all the coplete list? I get this at the end: [list output truncated]

Comment: It's up to you. Take a look here for more [info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: Try `summary(data_1)`